# Modify outcome of match regardless of which case evaluated

Tags: scala

Easy one!  Given the following:

```
print(1 to 100 map {
    case n if n % 10 == 0 => "Divisible by ten!"
    case n if n % 5 == 0 => "Divisible by five!"
    case n => n
})
```

What would be the most conscience way of making it so that each iteration was also followed by a newline?  I'm looking to minimize the number of expression blocks necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
1 to 100 map {
    case n if n % 10 == 0 => "Divisible by ten!"
    case n if n % 5 == 0 => "Divisible by five!"
    case n => n 
} foreach println _
```

Or

```
println(
    1 to 100 map {
        case n if n % 10 == 0 => "Divisible by ten!"
        case n if n % 5 == 0 => "Divisible by five!"
        case n => n
    } mkString "\n"
)
```